# Alternative formulation of the Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, analytic-functions

Can all real periodic functions be written in the following form?: $$f(x) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)+b_n \sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$

Comment: This function is not periodic

Comment: @Jules Besson  Why is it not periodic?

Comment: Why would it be ?

Comment: Because it's composed of a superposition of only periodic functions...

Comment: It is an infinite sum, you’re gonna have to exhibit a period for me please

Comment: What's the reason you said it's *not* periodic?

Comment: The period would be $\sup{n, n\in \mathbb{N}}= \infty$

Comment: Okay I understand now, we're looking at a sum akin to the integral of (sin(k/x) + cos(k/x))dx. I don't feel like the downvote was warranted though

Comment: Not me for the downvote. If it helps you should have added more details, why you think it should work. Maybe by doing that you could have figured it out for yourself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions you are describing (provided some convergence) are absolutely not periodical, you should have $ \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda} nx$ as variables for $\lambda$ periodical functions… You can take $a_n = 2^{-n}$ to see for yourself.

Secondly the set of periodical functions is not stable by addition… You need to have rational period to ensure it. And even if you consider that, it is not closed which means infinite sum won’t work.

Lastly sin(2x) is periodical but not in the set you are describing.